# Match small polygons that are within a bigger polygon to collectively have the geometry of the bigger one

Tags: polygon, geometry, arcgis-pro, editing

I have two layers: The green polygons (with detailed information on inhabitants in the attribute table) and the blue ones with blue boundary, which are housing blocks (with the shape needed). The red parts are those areas of the blocks that are not covered by green polygons.

I need the green polygons to completely cover the red area. However, each green polygon needs to cover "it's" red part in order to get the symbology right that is based on the info in the attribute table of the green features.

I tried to solve the problem using the [Symmetrical Difference](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm) tool to identify/create the red parts as a starting point but they only share the attributes with the big, blue polygon. I cannot think of any other way. Doing it manually is not an option.

[image: Screenshot of green polygons not matching blue polygons]

Comment: Try [eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I used eliminate and it worked. But beforehand, I had to split all the slivers to allocate the right parts to the right polygon. I did so by buffering the green polygons, then using polygon to line (https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/polygon-to-line.htm) and then the split polygons with lines tool (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431), resulting in incomprehensible cuts that were good enough for my cause.